# TypeError: props.results.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

Trying figure out how to solve the error with .map, but having trouble identifying how. Trying to convert my react app to useState and useEffect and the other parts are functioning, but this error keeps popping up. Before converting to useState and useEffect, the app functioned fine. But after converting, I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: props.results.map is not a function
EmployeeTables
src/components/EmployeeTables.js:21
  18 |     <th>DOB</th>
  19 |   </tr>
  20 | </thead>
> 21 | <tbody> 
     | ^  22 |   {props.results.map(
  23 |     ({ login, picture, name, phone, email, dob }) => (
  24 |       <tr key={login.uuid}>
```

Here is the code I have.

```
import React from "react";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import "../style.css";

function EmployeeTables(props) {
      return (
        <table>
          <thead className = "header"
          style = {{
            backgroundColor: props.theme === "green" ? "#5cb85c" : "white",
            textAlign: "center"
          }}>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th onClick={props.sortByName}>Name</th>
              <th>Phone</th>
              <th onClick={props.sortByEmail}>Email</th>
              <th>DOB</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody> 
            {props.results.map(
              ({ login, picture, name, phone, email, dob }) => (
                <tr key={login.uuid}>
                  <td>
                    <img src={picture.thumbnail} alt=''></img>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {name.first} {name.last}
                  </td>
                  <td>{phone}</td>
                  <td>{email}</td>
                  <td><Moment format="MM/DD/YYYY">{dob.date}</Moment></td>
                </tr>
              )
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      );
}

export default EmployeeTables;
```

Any help provided is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to log props and see if results comes as array.

Comment: Where have you use useEffect and useState and how

Comment: This will happen if `props.results` is not an array, but something else like an object. Print it out to see what it is, and debug from there

Comment: @Sodhi saab - Thank you. I put in a console.log and I get 3 responses. The first 2 are empty objects while the 3rd one has the results I want.

Comment: @Shubham Khatri - Thank you. I used useEffect and useState on a different component, but wasn't sure how or if I needed to implement it on this one. But before I implemented it on the other component, it was functioning fine. Actually, the app is functioning, except for one aspect.

Comment: @Jayce444 - I logged it and got 3 responses. Not sure what to do there, but the first 2 were empty arrays, while the third was the expected array of objects with the data. I suspect it's asynchronous, but not sure how to proceed to rectify that.

Comment: Maybe you can add a default value for the results prop. If you refactor the function parameter to be: `({ results = [], ...props })` then you can use `results.map`. From where are you getting the prop?

Answer (score 0):

You can do following these ways below:

1. Check props.results like: props.results && props.results.map({login, picture, name, phone, email, dob } => // continue your code)
2. Set default results state from parents component of EmployeeTables component like: const [results, setResult] = useState([]) in hooks

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense, but I'm not sure where to put it. Before the return or where the props.results.map is, or #2 is before return and #1 is where the props.results..map is.

Comment: I added an example code for another answer. You can check it

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your are getting the array data in `results` prop.

It's  possible that you are getting the props.results from API and it's value is  `undefined` on component mount or getting the data from any other resource which takes little time to load and pass the data after component rendering.

So never rely on prop while using the native utils like `map` or `find`. And to avoid such type of issues use the default props.

```
EmployeeTables.defaultProps({
   results: []
})
```

Its also good to use to proptypes so that you get the helpful console warning when passing invalid data type.

And while using the native function like `map` always incorporate the condition before using it and make sure that you are getting array type data in prop.

```
{Array.isArray(props.results) && props.results.map(
              ({ login, picture, name, phone, email, dob }) => (
                <tr key={login.uuid}>
                  <td>
                    <img src={picture.thumbnail} alt=''></img>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {name.first} {name.last}
                  </td>
                  <td>{phone}</td>
                  <td>{email}</td>
                  <td><Moment format="MM/DD/YYYY">{dob.date}</Moment></td>
                </tr>
              )
            )}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 !props.results ? null : props.results.map( () => ...)
}
```

This should work, it might be `props.results` empty on initial load.